# Why am I not able to stream games with Steam Link?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, steam-in-home-streaming, steam-link

I want to use my pc in my bedroom as a host and play games on tv in living room with Steam Link. I'm hoping I can play games smoothly with 4K 100hz. Unfortunately, it is so laggy and lossy. Here is the detailed spec:

Host (PC):

- CPU: i7-9700K
- RAM: 16GB
- GPU: GeForce RTX 2080

Client (TV):
Sony A90J

Network:

- Model: Netgear AC1750 Gigabit Router R6400
- Bandwidth: 1GB

Steam Link Settings:
Balanced

I want to know the cause of the bad performance, since my pc and tv seem perfectly fine. Should I have a router for game streaming? Any respond would be appreciated.

Comment: Is everything connected with LAN cable with proper category (i.e. Cat.6 or Cat.6a)? btw, I don't think your PC can achieve 4k 100fps (depends on game though), since even my PC (i7 12700KF / 3080 / DDR5 32GB, everything liquid cooling) can't keep up with 4k 100fps (again, depends on game). Moreover, since you're trying to stream, it needs extra processing power for encoding. What kind of games are you planning to play?

Comment: 4k at 100hz is a lot of data to push over a network.  Have you tried lowering this to something else? 1440p or 1080p? I bet it would improve a lot.

Comment: Do you mean "Steam Link" the app, or "Steam Link" the hardware? The latter only supports 1080p

Comment: @Sky-AT I'm connecting everything with Cat 5e LAN cable, and I'm testing with God of War 2018

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft "Steam Link" the app on android TV

Comment: @TimmyJim nah, I wanna play games at 4K, I won't consider lowering the resolution

Comment: I've calculated the needed bandwidth with [this](https://k.kramerav.com/support/bwcalculator.asp) site, and 4k 100hz needs about 10Gbps, which is 10 times higher than your bandwidth. If your TV doesn't have 10GbE RJ45 port, then you won't be able to play at 4k 100hz (or even if they do I assume it'd still stutter).

Comment: Thanks! but I also looked into [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/cloudygamer/comments/i925o3/minimum_bandwidth_to_stream_4k120hz_over_lan/g1cgclm/) site, some said 1 GB connection can handle the max of 4K@120hz.

Comment: @Skye-AT: That's not true. Steam link uses H.265 compression, so the actual bandwidth required is significantly less. The real issue is compressing 4k 100hz H.265 in real-time. I doubt even an RTX 3090 could do that.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Oh, I didn't know that. In that case yes it'd be more lower bitrate. I don't know if Steam link uses nvenc, but if it uses it, it won't take so much processing power (but if it's just using normal x265 then it'd be almost impossible to play/stream). I don't know if it can handle encoding while playing game at 4k@100hz, though.